# How can i break redirect loop?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect, middleware

I want to write 'Login Required' middleware.
So i did this

```js
module.exports = (req, res, next)=>{
    if(req.user === undefined){
        console.log('Login Required')
        res.redirect('/login')
    }
    next();
}
```

And I want to use this middleware to app-level middleware.

`app.use(loginCheck)`

And there's infinite redirection loop

I wan't to use this middleware at everywhere but not '/login'.
Is there a way to solve this problem using 'app.use(loginCheck)'?

Comment: Add a check for url `if(req.user === undefined && !req.url.startsWith('/login'))`

Comment: @Molda Thank you !!
I changed like this
`module.exports = function(){
    return (req, res, next)=>{
        if(req.user === undefined  && !req.url.startsWith('/login')){
            console.log('Login Required')
            res.redirect('/login')
        }
        next();
    }
}`

`app.use(loginCheck());`
And It works !